# Swift - How to duplicate chosen UIImagePickerController photo like those 3d red/blue apps

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, photos

I'm trying to make an app similar to the 3D photo effect ones that have reds and blues offset from each other, see http://goo.gl/Z40Il5. I have followed a tutorial on how to apply a color filter to an image selected https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/13/2/designing-the-interface but I'm not quite sure how to duplicate the selected image to offset it from the original, any suggestions on even what to Google for tutorials would be helpful. I'm new to swift so not sure what most things are called, and I of course have tried googling this myself only to get non-useful links.

Any direction much appreciated.

Comment: As for images and filters : google CIFilter

Comment: This site is a bad place to ask for links to tutorials, guides, manuals. It is great when you can't get a specific piece of code working but not for "How do I get started with this" questions. I suggest that you take your time and learn the basics. Learn how stuff is called and then you will be able to google stuff a lot better.